# Why is Swift nil-coalescing returning an Optional?

Tags: swift, type-inference

First, I try mapping a `[String?]`, to get a `[String]`:

```
$ xcrun swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.30). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let j: [String?] = ["a", nil]
j: [String?] = 2 values {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = nil
}
  3> j.map {$0 ?? ""}
$R0: [String] = 2 values {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = ""
}
```

This makes perfect sense to me.  I nil-coalesce a `String?`, and I get a `String`.  But with `[AnyObject?]`, something strange occurs:

```
  4> let k: [AnyObject?] = ["a", nil]
k: [AnyObject?] = 2 values {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = nil
}
  5> k.map {$0 ?? ""}
$R1: [AnyObject?] = 2 values {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = (instance_type = 0x00007fff7bc2c140 @"")
}
```

I'm nil-coalescing optionals, but this time I get out an optional.  Why?

The [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) says `a ?? b` is shorthand for `a != nil ? a! : b`, but when I try that, I get out an array of non-optionals:

```
  6> k.map {$0 != nil ? $0! : ""}
$R2: [AnyObject] = 2 values {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = ""
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how `??` is supposed to work?  What is going on here?

Comment: Interesting question, for same reason this seems to work `let res: [AnyObject] = k.map { $0 ?? "" }`

Comment: Looks like a weird type inference issue with `AnyObject` and literals – this also works: `let k1 = k.map {$0 ?? String()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has come to my attention that Apple considered this a bug in Swift 2.

In Swift 3, the 1st example above still works, while the 2nd and 3rd examples are invalid syntax (with or without Foundation bridging).

Replacing the `AnyObject` declaration with `Any` works: `a ?? b` then behaves identically to `a != nil ? a! : b`, as the documentation says.

Answer (score 2):

The detailed behaviour is not well-documented, so, would change in the future Swifts.

But you should know coalescing operator has two overloads:

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T

@warn_unused_result
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T?) rethrows -> T?
```

In your case, Swift has chosen the latter for your code.

You can test with a simplified codes like:

```
let x: AnyObject? = "a"
x ?? ""
```

The inferred type (in Swift 2.2.1) becomes `AnyObject?`.
But this code is also valid.

```
let y: AnyObject = x ?? ""
```

String literals like `""` can be treated as variety of types. All of these are valid in Swift.

```
"" as String
"" as String?
"" as NSString
"" as NSString?
"" as AnyObject
"" as AnyObject?
```

So, with some unspecified reason Swift has chosen `AnyObject?`.
And, in case type inference can be ambiguous, you should use explicit type annotation, as suggested in appzYourLife's comment.

Comment: Interesting!  So it looks like nil coalescing is defined *in* Swift, i.e., it's not just special syntax.  But the ternary operator is special syntax, right?  Does this suggest that type inference rules for operator overloads are (perhaps unintentionally) different from those for built-in operators?

Comment: Maybe I can say yes for both questions. You cannot write any ternary operators in Swift, even if you try to overload existing `?:`. And about type inference rules, the fact is as you see. And I don't mean this fact is what it should be. Considering the use cases of nil coalescing operator, Swift should use non-Optional first strategy, I think.